# Trying to use xpath in order to select a text on desktop web browser

Tags: automated-testing, python, browser-automation, appium, chrome

This is the error I am getting below:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="select-input-a7c294b6-e242-44b4-b153-67f6f42ecf77-opt-0"]"}

I am adding sleep(10) testing to see if the page isn't loading but this isn't the case.

This is what I am using:

```
self.driver_web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-input-a7c294b6-e242-44b4-b153-67f6f42ecf77-opt-0"]').click()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this locator works in browser inspect. On doing what this element appears ?

Comment: Did you try explicit wait ? For element to be there present

Comment: @pdHide I haven't tried using explicit wait i will try now.  

I found this xpath using the browsers inspect and also using "xpath finder" extension

Comment: if you are expecting this element after a certain action , for example you click a button and expect a drop down . Then use explicit wait for the drop down element to appear .

Comment: @PDHide 
Hey,  I have been trying to use:

    self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="select-input-e82ca44d-eb91-465b-95a0-81865b5aa980-opt-0"]'))).click()

Comment: And then tried using this:


        self.wait2 = WebDriverWait(self.driver_web, 5)
self.driver_web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-input-a7c294b6-e242-44b4-b153-67f6f42ecf77-opt-0"]').click()

Comment: @PDhide but i wasn't able to resolve the issue.

Comment: https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-do-i-wait-for-element-on-screen-to-be-displayed-python/2505

Comment: You are using explicit wait wrongly , please see the 7th comment in the link

Comment: @PDHide

WebDriverWait(self.driver_web, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="select-input-a7c294b6-e242-44b4-b153-67f6f42ecf77-opt-0"]'))).click()


I tried doing this and it didn't work.

Comment: @pdhide sorry man i hope im doing this as you are telling me :/  i dont understand why this is happening

Comment: @pdhide hey i got it to work!

Comment: please add the answer

Answer (score 0):

Class and ID are auto-generating so I think that you should change xpath to contain (text(),'text of element') or anything that was fixed.